# laravel poimts to wrong $path, why can I clear it

Tags: path, laravel-8

I download a laravel project from live shared servel to local serve in laragon. When I serve the project, it throw the error "File does not exist at path" and pointed to the old pathe in the live serve. Image is attached. I tried config:clear and dump autoload but throw the same error

[image: error massage]

dump autoload and php artisan config:clear

Comment: Is the file there?

Comment: the problem is in the path to the file. it points to the old one in the live serve. I want to clear it.